# represent a django model which combines data from 2 other models

Tags: python, django, django-models

**Background**:

I scrape data from 2 sources for upcoming properties for sale, lets call one `SaleAnnouncement`, and the other `SellerMaintainedData`. They share many of the same field names (although some data can only be found in one and not the other). If an item is coming up for sale, there is guaranteed to be a `SaleAnnouncement`, but not necessarily `SellerMaintainedData`. In fact only about 10% of the "sellers" maintain there own site with relevant data. However those that do, always have more information and that data is more up to date than the data in the announcement. Also, the "announcement" is free form text which needs to go through several processing steps before the relevant data is extracted and as such, the model has some fields to store data in intermediate steps of processing (part of the reason I opted for 2 models as opposed to combining them into 1), while the "seller" data is scraped in a neat tabular format.

**Problem**:

I would ultimately like to combine them into one `SaleItem` and have implemented a model which is related to the previous 2 models and relies heavily on properties to prioritize which model the data comes from. Something like:

```
@property
def sale_datetime(self):
    if self.sellermaintaineddata and self.sellermaintaineddata.sale_datetime:
        return self.trusteeinfo.sale_datetime
    else:
        return self.latest_announcement and self.latest_announcement.sale_datetime
```

However I obviously won't be able to query those fields, which would be my end goal when listing upcoming sales. I have been suggested a solution which involves creating a custom manager which overrides the filter/exclude methods, which sounds promising but I would have to duplicate all the property field logic in the model manager.

**Summary (for clarity)**

I have:

```
class SourceA(Model):
    sale_datetime = ...
    address = ...
    parcel_number = ...
    # other attrs...

class SourceB(Model):
    sale_datetime = ...
    address = ...
    # no parcel number here
    # other attrs...
```

I want:

```
class Combined(Model):
    sale_datetime = # from sourceB if sourceB else from sourceA
    ...
```

I want a unified model where common fields between `SourceA` and `SourceB` are prioritized so that if `SourceB` exists it derives the value of that field from `SourceB` or else it comes from `SourceA`. I would also like to query those fields so maybe using properties is not the best way...

**Question**

Is there a better way, should I consider restructuring my models (possibly combining those 2), or is the custom manager solution the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another solution. What about using inheritance? You could create base class that would be abstract (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes). You can put all common fields there and then create separate model for SaleAnnouncement and SellerMaintainedData. Since both of them will inherit from your base model, you'll have to define fields only specific for the certain model.

Comment: While that would seem to solve the issue of repeated code in the form of common fields, it doesn't solve the bigger issue of linking the items together to represent one `SaleItem`, allowing me to query them as a unified model. If anything the contenttypes framework would seem more suited than an abstract base class, but even that doesn't seem to address the unification I am looking for

Comment: I'm really sorry, I must have misunderstood your question. I'd go with custom manager approach. Maybe something like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968501/single-custom-manager-for-multiple-models-in-django ?